# Vanishing of $\ell^2$-Betti numbers of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ for $n\geq 3$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lattices

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$In a paper I read the following claim:

By the work of Borel the $\ell^2$-Betti numbers of the cocompact lattices of $\GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ are known to all vanish when $n ≥ 3$. The same holds for the noncocompact ones like $\GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ by the $\ell^2$-proportionality principle.

The $\ell^2$-proportionality principle tell us that the $\ell^2$-Betti number of a finite index subgroup is just the product with the index. Hence, I'm assuming that the claim is saying that $\GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ is a finite index subgroup of a cocompact lattice of $\GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ or has a finite index subgroup which is a cocompact lattice. Is any of those two claims true? I've never studied lattices, so this may be trivial.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: These claims are not true: an overgroup/subgroup of finite index in a non-cocompact lattice is also a non-cocompact lattice.

Comment: I'd guess one should rather use the invariance of the vanishing of $\ell^2$-Betti numbers by measure-equivalence (given that all lattices in a given locally compact group are measure-equivalent). Maybe the proportionality principle you're referring at has a statement in terms of covolume of lattices.

Comment: @YCor Oh, this has sense. Thanks!! Somehow I tought inmediately in a wrong $\ell^2$-proportionality principle and forgot about the measure equivalence principle. Thanks!!

Comment: One tiny comment: you probably mean to talk about the special linear group since $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is not a lattice in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ (think about the case $n=1$ to see why).